# How to apply rxjava in recyclerview adapter & activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java, rx-android, bottomnavigationview

I have `MenuActivity` includes `Toolbar` at top, `FrameLayout` (containing Cart & Menu `fragments`) in the middle, `BottomNavigationView`  at bottom.

Execution steps,

1. `MenuFragment` has `RecyclerView` containing menus
2. User can select menus from it
3. Then it gets added to `CartFragment`
4. **Catch here is, I need show cart count badge which is placed in `BottomNavigationView`, something like cart icon along with badge same notification badge count.**

I have already achieved this scenario with the help of `Observable`.

> However, my problem is I want to implement same using **`RxJava`**.
>
> Like - User can add menus (emiting that data from `adapter` class) and
>   it gets observed in `MenuActivity` by manipulating badge count on cart icon.